# How to name methods that are public for the current package, however should be non-public for other packages?

Tags: python, pep8

PEP8 says:

> Use one leading underscore only for non-public methods and instance
>   variables.

If a class has methods that are intended for usage inside the current package, however not intended for usage in other packages, how do you name them? (i.e. not interface methods, however, they are used inside a package)

Leading underscore describes such a method as "private" which is not true. Name without leading underscore describes it as "free to use for everybody" which is misleading too.

So how to name them? How do you deal with it?

In my projects, this question usually pops ups, but I can't find answers at stack overflow. How others avoid it?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know of any convention for this case. Why don't you name them with leading underscore so that users of your package will know not to use them outside of the package. Then inside your package you use these "private" (or non-public) variables/methods. It is not perfect, but better than having "public" methods for this case; at least in my opinion.

Comment: There's no convention for "package private" method and variables. If parts of a package are referencing the the non-public parts of classes in other modules in the package, encapsulation is being broken and you might as well make them public, IMO.

Comment: Is such a question generally relevant? Or I'm doing something wrong from project organization perspective? Thanks

Comment: are you already using `__all__` in your modules as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python)?

Comment: 124bit: Relevant to what? Regardless, asking it there's a convention  or preferred way to do something not mentioned in the PEP 8 guidelines seems reasonable — even if the practice violates encapsulation `;¬)`.